# How to include classes in openerp views?

Tags: odoo

In my view their is an image field. so i copied it form res.partneras like below.

```
<field
    name="image"
    widget="image"
    class="oe_left oe_avatar"
    options="{"preview_image": "image_medium", "size": [90, 90]}"
    />
```

it generates an error.

but when i am using the code with no class as like below

```
<field
    name="image"
    widget="image"
    options="{"preview_image": "image_medium", "size": [90, 90]}"
    />
```

it will not generates any error. what is the difference and how to include that class to may view?

Comment: In OpenERP version 7.0-20140106-002615
I get

  "ValidateError

  Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!"

Answer (score 0):

did you activated the new v7 screen api?

for more info look at the developer memento:
https://www.odoo.com/files/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_latest.pdf

(page 6)